# Share PDF from NSData via Share Sheet

Tags: swift, pdf, nsdata, ios-sharesheet

The PDF file is generated on a web server and received as NSData. Swift is able to print this NSData object; however, it is not recognized on the share sheet by other applications that usually accept PDFs, like Google Drive. The only options shown on the share sheet are for printing and copying.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pdfObject)
let pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider)
return pdf!
```

Per sbarow's comment, I have also tried the following, but the `retrievePDFFromDisk` function returns nil:

```
func writePDFToDisk () {
    var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last! as NSURL
    docURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myDocument.pdf")
    pdfObject.writeToURL(docURL, atomically: true)
}

func retrievePDFFromDisk () -> AnyObject {
    let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myDocument", withExtension: "pdf")
    return pdf!
}
```

How can this data be properly advertised as a PDF to other applications from the share sheet?

Comment: Write the `NSData` to disk with `writeToURL:atomically:` and then use the path of the file to share.

Comment: I've edited the question to show an approach I have tried per your suggestion; `pdf` returns nil though. Must be missing something on the retrieval.

Comment: Try with `writeToFile:atomically`.

Answer (score 1):

Success! See below code:

```
func writePDFToDisk () {
    var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last! as NSURL
    docURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myDocument.pdf")
    pdfObject.writeToURL(docURL, atomically: true)
}

func retrievePDFFromDisk () -> AnyObject {
    var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last! as NSURL
    docURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myDocument.pdf")
    return docURL
}
```

In my instance, this can be simplified to the following:

```
func getPDFAsFile (pdfData:NSData) -> AnyObject {
    var docURL = (NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)).last! as NSURL
    docURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent( "myDocument.pdf")
    pdfData.writeToURL(docURL, atomically: true)
    return docURL
}
```